# Byacc $$ is untyped, how to resolve

Tags: bison, yacc, untyped-variables

I am using byacc to construct a grammar, but when i want to use *yyerrok* it says to me *byacc: e - line 44 of "bee.y", $$ is untyped*

```
    definition:
      | error ';'               {$$ = 0; yyerrok; } 
      | definition ID defFirst ';'      
      | definition ID '(' defSecond ')' stmt
      ;
```

how do i solve the problem?

Comment: Did you assign a type to the `definition` nonterminal?

Comment: No, do i have to assign a type to every nonterminal?

Comment: You get this message not because of `yyerrok` usage. The reason is `$$ = 0;`, i.e. you do not assign a type to the non-terminal `definition` (as @templatetypedef has said). With each production you can associate an *action*. Each action may return some *semantic value* which can be used in "higher" production. Moreover you can (or should) specify type of *semantic value* for each non-terminal and terminal.
Take a look at bison doc: www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html , especially pay attention to *semantic value* and *semantic action*.

Comment: @Grzes It has nothing to do with yyerrok whatsoever. It has only to do with the assignment to $$.

Comment: @EJP, this is exactly what I have said, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 2):

([Comments converted to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Grzes wrote:

> You get this message not because of yyerrok usage. The reason is `$$ = 0;`, i.e. you do not assign a type to the non-terminal `definition` (as @templatetypedef has said). With each production you can associate an action. Each action may return some *semantic value* which can be used in "higher" production. Moreover you can (or should) specify type of *semantic value* for each non-terminal and terminal. Take a look at bison doc: [www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html) , especially pay attention to *semantic value* and *semantic action*.

Comment: bison is for C language, do you know how can we handle it in byacc?

Comment: @EmadAghayi byacc is compatible with bison and also for the C language...